# Race Condition in Python Multiprocessing Aync_apply

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, race-condition

Could there be a race condition in the following code such that two async processes both try to update the global variable B at the same time in the call back function? If so, does python handle this or is it something we have to handle using locks? I have run this piece of code several times and have not had a race condition occur (that I know about) but not sure if that means it is impossible to happen.

Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

ky = 0
B = {}

def update(u):
    global B
    global ky
    B[ky] = u
    ky += 1

def square(x, y):
    return x*y

def runMlt():
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(square, args=(i, i + 1), callback=update)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runMlt()
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

The callback is executed by the master process, and changes the master process makes to those variables aren't visible to the subprocesses. No subprocess touches `B`.

(`B` doesn't need to be marked `global`, by the way; you're not assigning to the name, but just mutating it internally.)

Comment: Does this mean that the master process will process the result from each subprocess one by one? Does this act like queue?

Comment: There is [internally a queue in `mp.Pool`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L192), yes.

Comment: I would point out that the callback is handled by a thread in the main process, so if the main thread (or another thread) also needed to interact with `B`, there could be concurrent access issues.

Comment: @Aaron Not quite, due to the GIL.

Comment: @AKX the GIL does not prevent the need for mutexes in python threading. Not even all bytecodes are guaranteed to be atomic

Comment: @Aaron if I changed runMlt() such that I accessed B after the for-loop but before calling pool.close(), pool.close(), I would run in concurrent access issues? Could I run into concurrent issues, if I accessed B after doing pool.close() and pool.join()?

Comment: @indispinablenorm Again, no. If you access `B` after pool.close/pool.join, you will find it hasn't changed at all.

Comment: The thread that calls the callback in the main process is `pool._result_handler`, which is joined in `pool.join`, so there should be no need to protect access to `B` after the pool has joined. Before it (ie before you call `join`) it may be a good idea to protect calls to `B` with a `threading.Lock`

Answer (score -1):

Well, there aren't any race conditions because they aren't connected.   Remember, these are separate processes with separate address spaces.  The subprocesses will inherit the initial values, of the globals, but they are not shared.

If you need to communicate, you need to use something like a `Queue` to send the results back to "central control".

The `multiprocessing` module does have shared memory objects.

Comment: This is not quite correct as it only applies to the target function. The callback of `pool.apply_async` is called by a thread in the main process.